# Successful requests but no messages in Azure Service Bus

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I have an Azure function that sends messages to a Azure Service Bus queue with the following code :

```
class ServiceBusSenderClient:
    def __init__(self, fully_qualified_namespace, queue_name):
        credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
        servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient(fully_qualified_namespace=fully_qualified_namespace, credential=credentials, logging_enable=True)
        self.sender = servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name=queue_name)
    
    async def send_single_message(self, message:str):
        message = ServiceBusMessage(message)
        await self.sender.send_messages(message)
        logging.info("Sent a message to Service Bus")

    def close(self):
        self.sender.close()
```

When I trigger my function, I see incoming requests but no messages coming in my Service Bus Queue.

[image]

There is no errors from the Azure Function and all requests are successfull on Service Bus so I am a bit lost. What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Azure Service bus trigger will only trigger when the messages are received in the service bus queue. If the Function is running successfully, This means the messages are received and the function is triggered. You can enable logging to log your messages in Your service bus trigger

Answer (score 0):

Azure Function Service Bus queue trigger will only trigger and log the messages when after the messages are being sent to the queue:-

I created one Azure Functions Service Bus Queue and created one file to send the messages to the queue:-

**My `sendervicebus.py`**

Reference **[Link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/samples/sync_samples/send_queue.py)**

```py
import os
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage


CONNECTION_STR = 'Endpoint=sb://silicon-servicebus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=WFsJyG1PNWXcucDyQu4+OCKMti05g3J4U+ASbM1O3qA='
QUEUE_NAME = "myqueue"


def send_single_message(sender):
    message = ServiceBusMessage("Single Message")
    sender.send_messages(message)


def send_a_list_of_messages(sender):
    messages = [ServiceBusMessage("Message in list") for _ in range(10)]
    sender.send_messages(messages)


def send_batch_message(sender):
    batch_message = sender.create_message_batch()
    for _ in range(10):
        try:
            batch_message.add_message(ServiceBusMessage("Message inside a ServiceBusMessageBatch"))
        except ValueError:
            # ServiceBusMessageBatch object reaches max_size.
            # New ServiceBusMessageBatch object can be created here to send more data.
            break
    sender.send_messages(batch_message)


servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR, logging_enable=True)
with servicebus_client:
    sender = servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME)
    with sender:
        send_single_message(sender)
        send_a_list_of_messages(sender)
        send_batch_message(sender)

print("Send message is done.")
```

**Output:-**

[image]

After the messages are sent, I Triggered my Azure Functions like below:-

**`init.py:-`**

```py
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    logging.info('Python ServiceBus queue trigger processed message: %s',
                 msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

**Output:-**

[image]

You can also send the messages and then run the Function in a single code:-

**my init.py to send the messages and trigger the function:-**

```py
import logging

import azure.functions as func

import os
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage


CONNECTION_STR = 'Endpoint=sb://silicon-servicebus.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxxxxxxM1O3qA='
QUEUE_NAME = "myqueue"


def send_single_message(sender):
    message = ServiceBusMessage("Single Message")
    sender.send_messages(message)


def send_a_list_of_messages(sender):
    messages = [ServiceBusMessage("Message in list") for _ in range(10)]
    sender.send_messages(messages)


def send_batch_message(sender):
    batch_message = sender.create_message_batch()
    for _ in range(10):
        try:
            batch_message.add_message(ServiceBusMessage("Message inside a ServiceBusMessageBatch"))
        except ValueError:
            # ServiceBusMessageBatch object reaches max_size.
            # New ServiceBusMessageBatch object can be created here to send more data.
            break
    sender.send_messages(batch_message)


servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONNECTION_STR, logging_enable=True)
with servicebus_client:
    sender = servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(queue_name=QUEUE_NAME)
    with sender:
        send_single_message(sender)
        send_a_list_of_messages(sender)
        send_batch_message(sender)

print("Send message is done.")


def main(msg: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    logging.info('Python ServiceBus queue trigger processed message: %s',
                 msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```