# Using log analytics logs to track requests for auditing purposes

Tags: .net, azure-log-analytics, audit-logging

We have incoming requests processed by a chain of azure functions connected via service bus queues (the processing doesn't take a lot of time and these are not durable functions).

Can we rely on log analytics logs to track where each request is in the chain for auditing purposes?

It appears to be a convenient way for the tracking, but I'm worried about reliability. Is there a chance that the logs are lost without the application receiving any exceptions?

I'm also considering azure tables where an error should no go unnoticed for sure, but using logs is easier.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can *log the chain of requests* from *Azure functions to Service Bus* with both ***Azure Functions Diagnostic settings and Application Insights + Azure Service Bus Diagnostic Settings to get Service Bus Runtime Audit Logs.***

Refer my [**SO thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77578121/successful-requests-but-no-messages-in-azure-service-bus/77583190#) where I have utilized Azure Functions with service bus trigger, That triggers as soon as the message is sent to the Service Bus.

**Service Bus Logs:-**

Visit your ***Service Bus > Diagnostic Settings*** and send the Logs to your **Log Analytics workspace**:-

[image]

[image]

All the diagnostics with Queue Activity is logged:-

[image]

**Azure Functions Diagnostic Settings and Application Insights:-**

*Azure Functions connected to Application Insights:-*

[image]

You can also send the **Function App Logs to Log Analytics** Workspace via **Diagnostic Settings** like below:-

[image]

[image]

[image]